# how to pass data from json to css?

Tags: css, json, angular, typescript

I have a image folder in my project and there are some images like

```
img> auto_active.png ,auto_inactive.png
```

and also have a json file like

```
[
{"key":auto},
{"key":car}
]
```

and Html like that

```
<div class="india">
<img src="{{key}}_active.png"

</div>
```

I want to change image on hover so i am using css like this

```
.india:hover{
 background-image: url("img/{{key}}_inactive.png");

}
```

but this approach is not use-full to bind key with css.how can i bind json key with css to change image on hover?

Comment: You can use jQuery / JavaScript to change the CSS on HTML elements on your page.

Comment: @devlincarnate You can't change the styling of the `:hover` pseudoclass from JavaScript. (At least not just like that).

Comment: I assume your pairings are dynamic? if not, you could just write this out in your css

Comment: @GolezTrol - but you could add a [hover event](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) that changes the CSS style when triggered.

Comment: You have to use JS to dynamically append your key in the filename - then apply the updated CSS using jQuery's css method.

Comment: @devlincarnate Yes you could, but it seems the  question is if it's possible to let Angular replace the url in the CSS using the same magic it uses for the variables in the document.

Answer (score 0):

> but this approach is not use-full to bind key with css.how can i bind json key with css to change image on hover?

Create different CSS classes for `auto` and `car` and toggle classes on the `img`.